# Same Calculation giving different answer in different device

Tags: logic, problem-solving

I wonder if i try this calculation on `scientific calculator`,
i am getting `6/2(2+1) = 1`

and in `mobile device, online and normal calculators` it gives me,

```
6/2(2+1) = 9
```

from my knowledge and what i get taught, first one (answer = 1) was correct... but how normal calculator provide this? i am confused. please clarify..

i searched about this, found something called BODMAS rule was the reason for first one.. is it correct or anything else?

[image]

Comment: The relative order of multiplication and division is ambiguous. Some calculators prioritize one over the other, some go left-to-right, and _none of them are wrong_.

Comment: On the left one multiplication and division has equal precedence. On the right one multiplication has higher precedence than division (which is trash).

Comment: $6/2(2+1)=(6/2)\;.(2+1)=3.3=9$ is wrong!

Comment: @lasenH Not necessarily. If I told you that the radius and circumference of a circle were related by $r = c/2\pi$, then common sense should tell you that the $2$ and the $\pi$ stick "closer together" than the $c$ and the $2$. It's still ambiguous, and I _should_ have written $c/(2\pi)$ or $\frac c{2\pi}$, but calling it "trash" is a bit much.